# Cardinality of an interval in the real line

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Find a transfinite number that represents the cardinality of the open
>   interval $(0, 1)$ in terms of $\aleph_0$. Justify your answer.

I think the answer is $2^{\aleph_0}$. I want to know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Think about representing numbers in $(0,1)$ in binary.